# React Native - TextInput in header - Keyboard is constantly dismissed every time I input a new character

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

the code works perfectly fine on a web browser but on an ipad or iphone, every time i input a character into the text input, the keyboard dismisses itself. However, when I use this text input with the same settings on a screen instead of a header, it works perfectly fine without dismissing itself until i click outside of the keyboard.

here is the code for the search header. this component is the header of the search tab

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {search} from './SearchFunctionality.js'

export default class SearchHeader extends Component {
   constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.state={
           value: ''
       }      
   }

submitButtonHandler = () => {
    search(this.state.value)
}

render(){
     return (
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <Image
    style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
    source={{uri: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/youtube/images/a/a5/Kittisaurus.jpeg/revision/latest/zoom-crop/width/360/height/360?cb=20200102062324'}}
    />
    <TextInput type = "search" name = 'SearchBar' onChangeText= {(searchValue) => this.setState({value:searchValue})}
      placeholder = 'SEARCH'
      style={{ paddingLeft: 5, paddingRight: 5, width: 150, height: 40, borderColor: 'green', borderWidth: 3 }}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity style = {{height: 40, width: 70, justifyContent: 'center',  alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: 'green'}} onPress = {this.submitButtonHandler}>
        <Text>find</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

  );}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the TextInput is getting the value from the state and overwriting its own value. Try assigning the TextInput a value of this.state.value :

```
<TextInput 
type="search" 
name='SearchBar'
value={this.state.value}
onChangeText= {(searchValue) => this.setState({value:searchValue})}
placeholder = 'SEARCH'
style={{ paddingLeft: 5, paddingRight: 5, width: 150, height: 40, borderColor: 'green', borderWidth: 3 }}
    />
```

Comment: the keyboard is still dismissing itself